# Does the Kusto IngestionTime policy exist at extent level or record level?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

The documentation is little ambiguous in clarifying this, it says that IngentionTime of records is maintained -- but I guess it's quite logical to think that it will be maintained internally in Kusto at extent level -- so one value per extent -- because an entire extent is part of an atomic transaction when written to a kusto table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tables where the ingestion time policy is enabled, each record gets its own value for `ingestion_time()` (which is an internal `datetime`-typed column).

When an extent is created (at ingestion time), all records in the extent will have the same value for `ingestion_time()`. Later on, the extent may get merged with other extent(s) (so, to your question - there will not necessarily be one value per extent)

Comment: got it, so I think we can infer if we ensure that different extents have unique special tags (e.g. drop-by:<dateid>) that will prevent them from merging with one another, all the records in an extent will share the same datetime value.

Comment: a) That is true. b) it is _very_ not recommended to assign unique drop-by tags, as it will prevent the system to optimize itself and eventually it will hurt performance of the queries.

Comment: the rationale behind doing so is to simulate hive partitioned styled design where if we rerun a slice it is exactly going to overwrite that specific partition -- assigning unique tags does allow us with that design in kusto. Please suggest if there is any other alternative.

Comment: using `drop-by` tags is ok for the scenario where batches of data get reprocessed at the source, and as a result you 'replace' an old batch of data with a matching new one in ADX (as explained here: https://yonileibowitz.github.io/kusto.blog/blog-posts/advanced-data-management.html#tagging-and-replacing-extents-data-shards). What @AlexanderSloutsky meant is that *overusing* extent tags (e.g. assigning a *unique* tag for *each* ingestion operation) is not advised - See the 'performance notes' part: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/extents-overview#drop-by-extent-tags